# Formula to sum a field with try catch in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have a Database field whose datatype is String to save marks (it may be numeric or grade),In Crystal Reports how can get sum of this field,It has to sum only numeric value and skip grade(A,B,C) and get sum.

Comment: You can do this in the report itself, no need for C#.

Comment: In crystal report ,                                                                                              
 I am getting error while converting this field  "tonumber(field1)"  since this field contains number and alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

while writing sql query add one more column with (try_cast(Colmn1Name)) then we can easily convert this column to number and then to sum in crystal report